# how to make public transportation map?

Tags: transportation, overlapping-features

I have collected the public transport routes and i want to map a map that looks like [this](http://ptv.vic.gov.au/getting-around/maps/). My problem is i am not able to show the shared segments as parallel lines. I have not been able to find good resources on this. I have good experiences with making maps and GIS softwares. If this requires special tools , then i can learn those too. Although i am looking for a static map, any possibility of making an interactive map would be better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Schematics](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/12/12/create-route-maps-with-the-arcgis-schematics-extension/) - The ArcGIS Schematics extension provides a sophisticated data model and a comprehensive set of tools for creating, managing, analyzing, and displaying complex networks. Perhaps less well known is the fact that it contains tools to create custom schematic layouts. You can use ArcGIS Schematics to create maps for any linear network that you store as a geometric network or as a network dataset with the ArcGIS Network Analyst extension